# Tornado give priority to GET

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, rest, tornado

I am implementing a multithreaded API in Tornado.

When I use POST on an endpoint, it allocates one thread to do some calculations then return.
Meanwhile it's doing this calculations, sometimes I cannot make a GET to the same endpoint: it blocks until the calculations have ended. But the GET is fast and I need to do it istantaneously.

How can I solve this problem? It exists some mechanism to give priority to GET?

Comment: code of the POST method would really help here

Comment: also, make blocking functions are called through executors https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#calling-blocking-functions

Comment: multithreaded API should be OK. Could you show some codes about your demo and how do you find it blocks ?   I guess you may not use rightly with `run_in_executor`?